# Model selection in Weka through cross validation for regression problems

Tags: regression, model-selection, cross-validation, weka

Does anyone know an approach to performing model selection in Weka through cross validation for regression problems?

As far as I can tell, the cross validation is implemented in Weka just to assess the performance of the classifier. I guess that calling Weka API from Java might solve the problem, but is there a GUI-based approach?

Comment: Compared to the message posted on [weka ml](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.weka/25217) (notwithstanding the cross-post on [MetaOptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/5656/model-selection-in-weka-through-cross-validation-for-regression-problems)), do you mean you want to compare different regression models, or just to optimize a given model with e.g., cross-validation?

Comment: @chl In fact he should do both to get reliable results =)

Comment: @mbq is right. However, the first step is to optimize some specific regression models. @chl: unfortunately, the weka ml community didn't come with a useful response.